# Secure a IIS directory while allowing angular access

Tags: angular, iis

I have an angular 4 app on an IIS 8 backend. The angular app gets its configuration from a JSON file stored in assets/data/config.json. The request is via httpClient.get() method. Problem is I need to have the angular app to receive the file when needed but I would like to prevent somebody to type www.mysite.com/assets/data/config.json and get the file. Also I would like to make sure nobody can post via http to this file (I think that's by default but I am not an IIS expert so I figure I ask anyhow).
Any help and/or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can secure the file by only allowing requests from the local (or your app domain) to get it and forbid access if the request comes from a different domain. You accomplish this by using one of the modules in IIS. Still this is not entirely secure as it relies on an HTTP header that can be spoofed.

I suggest you write the config file to the browser through the page that hosts the Angular app (default.aspx or index.aspx) and then forbid the file to be accessed directly from HTTP.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. IIS is the hosting server. I am not using asp for the angular app. I do have a asp.net core web api the app accesses. I wonder if there is a way to pass a parameter or something to a non secure api call...

Comment: You don’t need asp for the angular app. You just need the app hosting page (index.html) to be generated by the server (hence index.aspx) and that way you can include the config in the index page without exposing it over HTTP.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Do you have an example of how to embed a json file in the index.aspx page? How would the app then access it?

Comment: You would read the file in the aspx codebehind and spit it out as JSON in the page. That way it will be a globally available to any JavaScript code, including the Angular app. I can’t provide you an example right now as I’m the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON data should be coming from restful endpoints hosted on a back-end server. Then you can use JSON web tokens in order to secure your endpoints and allow only logged in users to retrieve the data from the APIs after making sure that they have a valid token.

Angularjs is used to develop SPA applications which are downloaded to the end user browser when he navigates to the site. In this case, I don't guess you can secure that file (even if that can be done on IIS folders, how would your angular service access it, I am curious to know if there is such a solution)

Comment: Thank you! It's a configuration file so the angular app should be able to get it without logging in.